# In Oracle PL/SQL, what algorithm is used to calculate the signature of a remote procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle PL/SQL, what algorithm is used to calculate the siganture of remote procedures? I googled around and found a few references saying Oracle used MD5 for some signatures, but I did not find any specific statements regarding the algorithm that is used for remote procedures.

Comment: Are you talking about [RPC signatures](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_dependencies.htm#ADFNS99977)?

Comment: If by RPC you mean procedures in a different database, then yes. I'm in a PL/SQL class and this is new to me, but I'm familiar with signatures such as CRC and MD5, and I wondered what Oracle uses.

Comment: I'd say your answer lies in the link Alex provided. I don't think it has anything to do with hashing schemes like MD5; a signature in this context is just the procedure's name and parameters.